# Wireless mouse starts lagging (sometimes stopping completely) at seemingly random moments

Tags: kubuntu, mouse

I'm not sure if this is a KDE issue or a problem with KUbuntu, but seemingly at random moments the mouse starts lagging...

It seems impossible to drag the cursor around while it was working perfectly seconds ago...

Only thing that fixes it is rebooting. I have tried with 2 different Logitech mice (both with unified receiver and MX master also in Bluetooth connected mode) and they both result in the same problem I have tried a wired Trust mouse and that one seems to keep working fine. I already did all the updates... have no clue what could be causing this. Anyone has a solution to this or a way to diagnose the problem?

Here are my system specs:

[image: system specs]

Although in the meantime I have upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 (hoping that that would solve the problem)

Comment: Have you tried using mouse closer to Unified Receiver? Mouse battery fully charged?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, it's fully charged an 2 cm away from the receiver.> I also upgraded the receiver firmware and tried another unified receiver... Nothing works :(